# How do I input a math function without Python running it?

Tags: python, math

I want to define a function which takes in a mathematical function as an input (such as `np.sin(x)` as an example) but I want it to essentially store it and have a random number generator put random numbers into it.

I know how to do it by directly inputting the code but I want to know how I can do it as a user which only sees the console.

So using np.sin(x) again,

```
def function(np.sin(x)):
    x=random.uniform(0,1)
    return value of np.sin(whatever the random number was)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function as parameter, not the evaluated function:

```
def function(func):
    x=random.uniform(0,1)
    return func(x)

function(np.sin)
```

That said it is not clear what you want to achieve, but you'll get a different random output at each call. Also, for such a trivial case, you should better use directly the numpy function:

```
np.sin(random.uniform(0,1))
```